# Ajax error every time open view

Tags: ajax

i want to create new view but every time i make selection like user, content etc. i got this error

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging
>   information follows. Path: /dru/system/ajax StatusText: Internal
>   Server Error ResponseText:  registrar_frameset({ a_id: 48873,       //
>   edit this to pass your portfolio ID, drid:
>   'as-drid-2416478692338427'});     // edit this to pass your Domain
>   Registrant ID

Comment: Does your browser console have ajax request url the same as your domain?

Comment: i think so, i try on mamp all working fine. but when move to live domain. the massage start coming out every time i use view. you think this have something relate to server

Comment: What I mean does the addresses match with each other after type selection in places presented in this picture https://dyp.im/gllurylgYJ ? (please edit if unapproapriate)

Comment: just install firefox now. i got the real error now.....

TypeError: this.iframeWindow.jQuery is not a function .

Error come from this code:

/**
 * Event handler: dispatches events to the overlay document.
 *
 * @param event
 *   Event being triggered, with the following restrictions:
 *   - event.type: any
 *   - event.currentTarget: any
 */
Drupal.overlay.eventhandlerDispatchEvent = function (event) {
  if (this.iframeWindow && this.iframeWindow.document) {
    this.iframeWindow.jQuery(this.iframeWindow.document).trigger(event);
  }
};

Comment: So your Drupal page in iframe doesnt have jQuery included. I would pursue answer provided by @Mirakolous further by checking what version of jQuery you have in the admin view page/overlay frame.

Comment: already try with jquery update and set to 1.5 for admin page. It still same. what i do now is avoid using any popup and disable jquery update. my web just running fine when i avoid this two thing. What i did't understand, why everything fine in mamp?

Comment: If your live domain is http://example.com/dru then that request should resolve. Problem might then be with server setup. I would try to verify that you can get 200 status from http://example.com/dru/system/ajax and check server logs and drupal logs otherwise. Im sorry but I have little experience working with drupal instances working with subdirectories

Comment: already try with main directories. same also because when i move to main, error still same. i think server got problem. i got massage almost every week their server got hit by ddos. i think same of their system maybe got problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment this, but I do not have the reputation. If you are using jQuery Update module, make sure it is set to 1.5 for the admin pages.

Comment: yes, i use jQuery update module. if i off module all fine. but if i enable even popup module it still come even jQuery module is in off condition